# minimum number of steps

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to return a minimum number of steps required when moving from one  point to another point on a two dimensional map with blocked steps.

```
0 – cell is empty, 
1 – cell is blocked, 
5 – from point (A), 
6 – to point (B).
```

Can anyone help with the solution of this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I think that you can approximate it with a graph, then apply the Dijkstra algorithm

Comment: @CristianTraìna I started with creating 2 loops one for x and one for y, and inside a if statement to start checking the path. From there I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: @CristianTraìna Dijkstra is used on graphs with weighted edges. There's no reason to use it here. Simple breadth first search will work.

Comment: @Mark_M yes, you're right, there's no improvement in using Dijkstra in terms of computational complexity, but the matrix can be easily converted to a graph which every link has `1` as weight, and then just use the already-existing algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a technique that's an implementation of breadth-first search, which is a standard algorithm for finding shortest distances in an unweighted graph.

You will need a queue (a first-in, first-out data structure) which we can implement with an array and an data structure to keep track of which nodes we visited and their parents (i.e. the node from which we arrived). We can use a Map of object for that.

Start with you starting node and add it to the queue. Then, while the queue is not empty:

- shift a node off the queue
- find it's neighbors
- if the neighbor is not in the parents map add it to the queue and the neighbors map
- repeat until you find your destination

If you don't find the destination, it's not reachable. At the end your parent map will allow you to trace the steps from your destination to the start by following the node->parent trail. You can use this to get the count and create the path.

The following code uses a few helper functions to print the graph and to find neighbors given a node's coordinates. To make it a little more interesting, I've used a maze with a more complex solution that the one in the question.

```js
// make a slightly harder maze
var multiArr = [
    ['0','0','0','0','1','5','0'],
    ['1','0','1','0','0','1','0'],
    ['0','0','0','1','0','1','0'],
    ['1','1','0','1','0','1','0'],
    ['0','0','0','1','0','1','0'],
    ['6','1','0','1','0','0','0']
];
/* the coordinates of our start, hard coded for simplicity */
let coord = [0, 5]

/* find the neighbors of a given coordinate
   only return those that are not equal to 1 and
   don't go off the edge of the map */
function getNeighbors(arr, coord) {
    let height = arr.length;
    let width = arr[0].length;
    return [[1,0],[-1, 0], [0,1], [0,-1]].reduce((a, c) => {
       let n = c.map((d, ind) => d + coord[ind])
       if (n[0] >= 0 && n[0] < height && n[1] >= 0 && n[1] < width && arr[n[0]][n[1]] != 1) a.push(n)
       return a
    }, [])
}

/* breadth first search */
function bfs(coord, multiArr) {
    let queue = [coord]
    /* keys for parents will be formed by joining doordinates with _ since we can's use the raw array */
    let parents = new Map([[coord.join('_'), undefined]])

    while (queue.length){
        let curr = queue.shift()
        let neighbors = getNeighbors(multiArr, curr)
        for (node of neighbors) {
            if(parents.has(node.join('_'))) continue
            let cell = multiArr[node[0]][node[1]]
            parents.set(node.join('_'), curr)
            queue.push(node)            
            if (cell == 6 )  return getPath(node, parents)              
        }
    }
    console.log("no path")
}

/* take the parents array from bfs() and print the result */
function getPath(node, parents) {
    let curr = node
    let length = 0
    while(curr = parents.get(curr.join('_'))){
        multiArr[curr[0]][curr[1]] = '*'
        length++
    }
    console.log('min length: ',length)
    console.log('solution:')
    for (row of multiArr){
        console.log(row.join('  '))
    }
}

/* engage */
bfs(coord, multiArr)
```

Comment: Mark_M Thank you for your detail explanation! At the end this is what I needed an Explanation on how to give a solution to this problem so, I can make a more detailed research and practice on this subject!

Comment: The solution is good but instead of using the queue you could have been economy the space and fill up the visited nodes in the multiArray with a value different than 0 or 1. Lets say "V" like visited.